# Why does kivy fail when used with python's "elevate()" function?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, elevated-privileges

When using the elevate() function from the [elevate](http://%20https://github.com/catb0t/elevate) module, kivy is unable to start. The relevant section of code is as follows:

```
from elevate import elevate
from os import environ

environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
environ['KIVY_WINDOW'] = 'sdl2'

elevate()
```

Later on, I give code for a kivy app and attempt to run it. I receive the following error when doing so:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-10-04_91.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc3, git-20c14b2, 20200615
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Kivy-2.0.0rc3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.5 (default, Aug  2 2020, 15:09:07) 
[GCC 10.2.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 185 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer, img_gif ignored)
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2.dev0, git-f0a8217, 2020-09-27 (installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivymd-0.104.2.dev0-py3.8.egg/kivymd/__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
No protocol specified
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'No available video device'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Kivy-2.0.0rc3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 70, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Kivy-2.0.0rc3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Kivy-2.0.0rc3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 982, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Kivy-2.0.0rc3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 287, in create_window
    self.system_size = _size = self._win.setup_window(
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 112, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 74, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

How can I resolve this? I have tried setting `environ['DISPLAY'] = '*:0'`, but receive the same error, except without the "no protocol found". Note that this is an app which must run on more machines than just my own, so I need a fix that can be put into the code rather than a one-time command to run with bash.

I should also mention, the app works fine when I run `sudo python3 main.py`. It's only when I use `python3 main.py` (which causes the `elevate()` function to prompt me with a login) that I get this error.

Comment: Try `elevate(graphical=False)`. I also had to remove the `environ` stuff.

Comment: What if I want the graphical prompt? Is there any way to accomodate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it fails is that after switching to root, the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` environment variables are not set. You can set these to solve that issue. Here is a sample that will do that:

```
def is_root():
    return os.getuid() == 0

file_name = os.path.join(gettempdir(), 'f.txt')
if not is_root():
    print('saving DISPLAY:', os.environ['DISPLAY'])
    print('saving XAUTHORITY:', os.environ['XAUTHORITY'])
    with open(file_name, mode='w') as f:
        f.write(os.environ['DISPLAY'] + ' ' + os.environ['XAUTHORITY'])
else:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        txt = f.readline()
    tokens = txt.split()
    os.environ['DISPLAY'] = tokens[0]
    os.environ['XAUTHORITY'] = tokens[1]
    print('restored DISPLAY:', os.environ['DISPLAY'])
    print('rstored XAUTHORITY:', os.environ['XAUTHORITY'])
    os.remove(file_name)
```

This is just a proof of concept. You should consider security and choice of `file_name`. Obviously, this applies only to `posix` systems and will not work on Windows. I considered trying to use the python `tempfile` module, but I believe any `tempfile` written will be removed before you have a chance to read it. I haven't tested that.